# 'Team context aware' query in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Previously, in Azure DevOps, query macros like `@CurrentIteration` used the team context to return their results in the web portal.

Recent changes have changed this behaviour, so that specifying the `@CurrentIteration` macro now requires a specified team. Whilst i understand the reasons behind this (making the query more predictable, the ability to add multiple team based parameters in a single query), it does mean that it is more or less impossible to create queries that can be shared between teams. Each team has to make a copy, and plug in their own team name.

Is there any way to restore the previous behaviour?

Comment: I am also running into this situation where we had queries that we shared across all of our teams no longer working because we need to hard core the team name under the @CurrentIteration.  I hope there is some help on this :(

Answer (score 0):

You can create one query with "Or" operators for all the teams:

[image]